# dynamodDB putItem: "UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'L' found in params.Item"

Tags: arrays, amazon-dynamodb

I am attempting to "putItem" a new record into a dynamoDB database but failing on attempts to include an Array in the data.  My params.Item looks like the following:

```
msg.params.Item = {
    fileName: {S: "filename"}, // database is keyed on filename
    userEmail: {S: "emailaddress"},
    transcription: {S: "text here"},
    features: {L: [ { "relevance": {S: "0.900906"}, "text": {S: "keyword"}} ]}
};
```

I repeatedly get the error "UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'L' found in params.Item['features']".  I assume I have somehow formatted the "features" array incorrectly, but I can't figure out where my error is.  I have tried many different incantations of the array.  Any help appreciated as there are shockingly few online examples of working dynamoDB putItem javascript using arrays.

FYI: I am using node.js inside of Node-RED, which may explain the odd code, but I had this working just fine with a Cloudant database before.  Only dynamoDB is choking on this array.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing `M` for map:

`features: {L: [ { "relevance": {S: "0.900906"}, "text": {S: "keyword"}} ]}`

should be

`features: {L: [ {M: {"relevance": {S: "0.900906"}, "text": {S: "keyword"}}} ]}`

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this variant, but still got the error message "UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'L' found in params.Item['features']".  Perhaps this is an artifact of the dynamoDB Node-RED node that I'm using (https://github.com/michaelmruta/node-red-contrib-aws-dynamodb/blob/master/dynamodb.html).

Comment: @TedBarnett are you able to insert the item if you exclude `features`?

Comment: @TedBarnett I may be jumping the gun on this one, but it seems as though the library you linked is [wrapping the item](https://github.com/michaelmruta/node-red-contrib-aws-dynamodb/blob/master/dynamodb.js#L76). According to the [npm doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-data-types#quick-example), passing a regular data structure into `attr.wrap()` adds the appropriate labeling DynamoDB requires.

Comment: Yes.  If I exclude the "features" object, the putItem works fine.

Comment: @TedBarnett Hm, very interesting. And the values stored on the database side look valid?

Comment: My putItem works perfectly as long as I do not include the "features" array.  I stripped the entire putItem down to this setup code:

'// Set up DynamoDB data
msg.topic = "putItem";
msg.params = {};
msg.params.Item = {
    fileName: msg.finalResult.filename, // database is keyed on filename
    features: msg.features.keyword
};'

The features array looks like the following:
'[ { "relevance": "0.992715", "text": "sample question" }, { "relevance": "0.655014", "text": "testing" } ]'

I get the same error (UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'L' found in params.Item['features'].

Answer (score 2):

The below code should create the item successfully. The DynamoDB data type need not be mentioned separately as long as it follows the below mapping.

**JavaScript Type -->     DynamoDB Type**

Array -->                L

Object   -->             Map

[JavaScript data type to DynamoDB data type mapping](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html)

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();    
var table = "files";    
var params = {
    TableName:table,
    Item:{
        "fileName" : "file1",
        "userEmail" : "abc@gmail.com",
        "transcription" : "transcription text",
        "features" : [{ "relevance":  "0.900906", "text":  "keyword"}]

    }    
};

console.log("Adding a new item...");
docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't the data type needed? It appears to be left out in this suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your `apiVersion`. I ran into this issue because I wasn't using the latest one, which is `2012-08-10`, not `2011-12-05`.